# How do I match multiple addresses in sed?

Tags: command-line, sed

I want to execute some `sed` command for any line that matches either the `and` or `or` of multiple commands: e.g., `sed '50,70/abc/d'` would delete all lines in range `50,70` that match `/abc/`, or a way to do `sed -e '10,20s/complicated/regex/' -e '30,40s/complicated/regex/` without having to retype `s/compicated/regex/`

Comment: With a bit of contortion, you can do the second part: `sed -e '10,40 { 21,29!s/complicated/regex/; }'`.  That selects lines 10 to 40, but only applies the substitute to lines other than 21 to 29 (i.e. 10 to 20 and 30 to 40).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### Logical-and

The `and` part can be done with braces:

```
sed '50,70{/abc/d;}'
```

Further, braces can be nested for multiple `and` conditions.

(The above was tested under GNU `sed`.  BSD `sed` may differ in small but frustrating details.)

#### Logical-or

The `or` part can be handled with branching:

```
sed -e '10,20{b cr;}' -e '30,40{b cr;}' -e b -e :cr -e 's/complicated/regex/' file
```

- `10,20{b cr;}`

  For all lines from 10 through 20, we branch to label `cr`
- `30,40{b cr;}`

  For all lines from 30 through 40, we branch to label `cr`
- `b`

  For all other lines, we skip the rest of the commands.
- `:cr`

  This marks the label `cr`
- `s/complicated/regex/`

  This performs the substitution on lines which branched to `cr`.

With GNU `sed`, the syntax for the above can be shortened a bit to:

```
sed '10,20{b cr}; 30,40{b cr}; b; :cr; s/complicated/regex/' file
```

Comment: That'll work OK in BSD `sed` too with the semicolon present. GNU `sed` would allow you to omit the semicolon; BSD `sed` doesn't.

Comment: That works for me. Also seems to work with >2 criteria by nesting the braces like `sed '1~2{50,70{/abc/p}}'`

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks, as always, for the edit and the info.

Answer (score 3):

To delete lines from 10 to 20 and 30 to 40 matching your complicated regex with GNU sed:

```
sed -e '10,20bA;30,40bA;b;:A;s/complicated/regex/;d' file
```

or:

```
sed -e '10,20bA' -e '30,40bA' -e 'b;:A;s/complicated/regex/;d' file
```

---

`bA`: jump to label `:A`

`b`: a jump without label -> jump to end of script

`d`: delete line

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `sed` has the facility for *multiple* selection criteria, my advice would be to step up to `awk`, where you can do something like:

```
awk 'NR >= 50 && NR <= 70 && /abc/ {next} {print}' inputFile
awk '(NR >= 10 and NR <= 20) || (NR >= 30 && NR <= 40) {
     sub("from-regex", "to-string", $0); print }'
```

Answer (score 0):

sed is excellent for simple substitutions on individual lines but for anything else just use awk for clarity, robustness, portability, maintainability, etc...

```
awk '
(NR>=50 && NR<=70) && /abc/ { next }
(NR>=10 && NR<=20) || (NR>=30 && NR<=40) { sub(/complicated/,"regex") }
{ print }
' file
```