# SED: remove pattern from two specific lines

Tags: regex, bash, sed

The following command will remove PATTERN from all the lines 13,14,15...29 containing it:

```
sed -i 13,29s/PATTERN// file
```

However, I want to remove PATTERN from only the 13th and 29th line. Obviously, I can use

```
sed -i 13s/PATTERN//;29s/PATTERN// file
```

but my pattern is long enough to make this inconvenient so I would like to specify the PATTERN only once. Any ideas? I've tried to search for an answer but found nothing.

Also, is there a valid reason why sed uses a comma instead of dash to match a range of lines? I find it illogical.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: store your pattern in a variable and repeat the variable?

Comment: Too complex. I'm searching for something more convenient.

Comment: well, i call that convenient too... alternative is awk. `NR == 13 || NR == 29` very handy too

Comment: Can you share the full command, please?

Comment: This is effectively the same question as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28825450/1426891), noting the difficulty in that answer of the "logical OR" between the two line-number addresses you're asking for.

Comment: em... i am really convinced using variable is convenient now...

Comment: The following command works: `sed -i '13{b cr};29{b cr};b;:cr;s/PATTERN//' file`

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr: That would involve using a function, so that's not a solution for me. P.S.: Sorry for my late reply, your comment was hidden.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr: Oh, now I understand what have you tried to tell me: `VAR=PATTERN;sed -i 13s/$VAR//;29s/$VAR// file`

Comment: @mYself oh. happy for you to realize that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the following is probably the closest thing to what could possibly be the answer to my question:

```
sed -i '13,29{14,28!s/PATTERN//}' file
```

A little longer answer with logical-or:

```
sed -i '13bA;29bA;b;:A;s/PATTERN//' file
```

Also, using a variable:

```
VAR=PATTERN
sed -i "13s/$VAR//;29s/$VAR//" file
```

Thanks to @Jeff Bowman [for redirection](/questions/28825450/how-do-i-match-multiple-addresses-in-sed), and @HuStmpHrrr for the advice to use a variable.

Answer (score 2):

use awk:

```
awk 'NR == 13 || NR == 29 { sub(/PATTERN/, "") } { print }' file
```

of course, you have to use awk compatible re here. https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Regexp.html#Regexp

the first part achieves your requirement, and the second part just print everything out. you can use redirect to put things in another file, and then move over to the original place.

Comment: As you say, this only prints out the specified lines with the PATTERN removed. As my input is a file, the command should be written to reflect that. Also, it's way more complex than using sed.

Comment: @mYself no. it should print out all content of the file with 13 and 29 line modified. and passing into a file is as easy as showed. what kind of solution are you looking for?

Comment: perhaps you tried my old answer. try this one on your browser now. or refresh first to make sure about it.

Comment: You're probably right as the command now outputs the whole content of file minus the PATTERN to stdout.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution.